# Android: how to send an event to another app

Tags: android, event-handling, broadcast

I'd like to send an event to other listening apps.

Is there something like `LocalBroadcastManager` and `BroadcastReceiver`? This method is restricted to the same process.

Comment: "This method is restricted to the same process" -- `LocalBroadcastManager` has that restriction. Regular system broadcasts (e.g., `sendBroadcast()` on `Context`) work across processes.

Comment: thank you! that is what I was looking for

Comment: please, can you show me an example?

Comment: [This pair of sample apps](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RemoteViews) communicate with each other using broadcasts.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to know which is the sender app id or package?

Comment: I don't think so. You can try calling `Binder.getCallingUid()` in `onReceive()`, but I suspect that it will return your own app's UID, not the UID of the sender.

Comment: unfortunately it isn't the sender's uid

Comment: You could require the sender to include this information in the `Intent` that is broadcast. The sender might forget to, and malicious senders might claim to be something else. In general, you need to think through the security of broadcasts, to avoid spoof senders or other apps monitoring the communications by registering as a receiver.

Comment: I'd prefer that android could do this, not a sender app.... it's a vulnerable communication

Comment: monitoring it's not a risk, but spoofing is a 100% risk

Comment: Your options are fairly limited. If you control both apps, use a custom `signature`-level permission, at least on Android 5.0+.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't control both apps

Comment: Then you are in trouble. You may need to switch to a different IPC approach, such as a bound service, where `Binder.getCallingUid()` will work.

Comment: I think it's not possible to spy the actions because the mechanism is made by Android by awakening only the right receivers. Broadcast is just a name, not a real fact, because it's a broadcast delivery of events managed by Android. It's not like an Ethernet where every peer can see the packets

Comment: Anyone can create a receiver, though, and register it to receive your broadcasts. Since you are working with arbitrary other apps, your only practical approach is to use implicit `Intents`, which means the monitor merely needs to have a `<receiver>` with the same `<intent-filter>` as yours.

Comment: but if the filter is kept secret between apps he cannot do anything

Comment: Any Android user can find out every `<intent-filter>` of every app on their device. There are no secrets here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `BroadcastReceiver`, but there are two conditions.

1. The other app (listening to your broadcast) needs to be open in background, and the BroadcastReciever should be registered before sending the broadcast from your app.
2. The other app will not come to fore ground on receiving the broadcast.

I would suggest the use of custom URL schemes using `intent-filters`. See example [Android intent filters](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html)